# Can I save timestamp in a video file on Android?

Tags: android, video, mp4, android-camerax, android-video-record

Now, I am trying to create a video recording application, I am going to use `Image analysis` of CameraX.(Why not `video capture`? I think `video capture` can not save the timestamp of every frame)

Have any way save fame with timestamp from `Image analysis`?

Thanks

Comment: See if [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311088/2057709) gives you ideas. If your video file is **only H.264** then you can try adding timestamp as bytes (of text/String _eg:_ `00:05:03`). Add that to ending of an H264 frame's bytes, it will later mux into MP4 with no issues. If your code is outputting MP4 then you can only edit it after recording is complete. Try to get the raw H264 bytes (before it's put into MP4) because it will be tedious to edit MP4 frames (one small change in total bytes means you'll also edit multiple other sections of MP4 to account for this new difference).

Comment: PS: See [this Android Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945911/2057709). There they are using Camera2 but you still need the equivalent setup in CameraX (_eg:_ use AVC as output type). If you can get to the raw H.264 bytes of a frame inside an Array then I can help you edit the array to include timestamp, then later you can mux the array's bytes into MP4...

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for your comment, It likes an answer can you copy them to an Answer, I will check it later.